# Collapsible div block nested within another to re-adjust the max height of the whole block

Tags: javascript, html, css

It was hard to explain the issue of the question in one line but to summarize:

I have collapsible div elements highlighted by a `.collapsible` class, and within we have a `.content` class. If the parent element is without the `.active` class the max height is set to null, but when active it is calculated with max height and then set as a style.

The JavaScript that runs it all:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
    });
}
```

Fairly straight forward, got it from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp). I've adjusted it a bit more and manipulated to better suit my functionality.

I tried to nest these collapsible and that's when things got strange, the child of the collapsible does calculate its correct max height and push the other content down.

Here is a JavaScript snippet of the bug in action:

```js
 var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  if (coll[i].classList.contains('active')) {
   var content_tmp = coll[i].nextElementSibling;
   if (content_tmp.style.maxHeight){
    content_tmp.style.maxHeight = null;
   } else {
    content_tmp.style.maxHeight = content_tmp.scrollHeight + "px";
   } 
  }
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   this.classList.toggle("active");
   var content = this.nextElementSibling;
   if (content.style.maxHeight){
    content.style.maxHeight = null;
   } else {
    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
   } 
  });
 }
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible"><span>Main Parent</span></button>
<div class="content">
  <button class="collapsible"><span>Child 1</span>       </button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to
      be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.
    </p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible"><span>Child 2</span></button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Some Text of child 2 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.<br><br><br>Some Text of child 2 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `content.style.maxHeight = null;` why that? should this not be none? `content.style.maxHeight = "none";`

Comment: The thing is, you are trying to use a code snippet for a single level collapsible list, but your desired outcome is a nested one, with 2 levels. You need to somehow differentiate the inner and outer collapsibles, and update the outer one's max-height again when the inner one is interacted with.

Comment: @HenriqueErzinger I figure it would be something like that but I'm having trouble calculating the new max height once an inner is activated. I got it to detect when only a inner hit clicked and I'm able to target the corresponding outer element. Just having a hell of a time recalculating the new max height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for parent collapsible elements on each click and adjust their max-height values. Another thing to keep in mind... once we start the transition, than we have to delay the max-height calculation. Would be easier with jQuery, but here is a plain JS solution:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var animationDelay = 200; /* Gotta delay max-height value */
function calcMaxHeight(elem) {
    var content = elem.nextElementSibling;
    if (elem.classList.contains("active")) {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = "0";
    };
    var nextParentContent = elem.closest(".content");
    if (nextParentContent !== null) {
        var nextParentCollapsible = nextParentContent.previousElementSibling;
        setTimeout(function() {
            calcMaxHeight(nextParentCollapsible);
        }, animationDelay);
    };
};
for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        calcMaxHeight(this);
    });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    padding: 0 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible"><span>Main Parent</span></button>
<div class="content">
    <button class="collapsible"><span>Child 1</span> </button>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to
            be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.
        </p>
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible"><span>Child 2</span></button>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Some Text of child 2 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.<br><br><br>Some Text of child 2 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69ndw3o8/3/)

You could probably improve this script, just wanted to show you a jQuery solution:

```js
$('.collapsible').on('click', function(e) {
 var thisCollapsible = $(this);
 var thisContent = thisCollapsible.next();
 thisCollapsible.toggleClass('active');
 if( thisCollapsible.hasClass('active') ) {
  thisContent.slideDown(200);
 } else {
  thisContent.slideUp(200);
 };
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="collapsible"><span>Main Parent</span></button>
<div class="content">
    <button class="collapsible"><span>Child 1</span> </button>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to
            be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.Some Text of child 1 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.
        </p>
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible"><span>Child 2</span></button>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Some Text of child 2 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.<br><br><br>Some Text of child 2 that is very long and needs to be pushed down.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [Playground here](https://jsfiddle.net/69ndw3o8/5/)